# SQL Trouble with correlated subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, h2

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT
  HALLS_REGISTRATION.ID,
  (
    CAST(
        (SELECT
           HALLS_REGISTRATION.MONEY_RECEIVED_NUMERIC
         FROM
           HALLS_REGISTRATION
         WHERE
           HALLS_REGISTRATION.ID = 2)
        AS DECIMAL
    )
    +
    (SELECT
       SUM(
           CAST(
               HALLS_REGISTRATION_PAID.PAID_MONEY
               AS DECIMAL
           )
       )
     FROM
       HALLS_REGISTRATION_PAID
     WHERE
       HALLS_REGISTRATION_PAID.REGISTRATION_ID = HALLS_REGISTRATION.ID
    )
  )
FROM HALLS_REGISTRATION;
```

this works fine, but it's not exactly what I want. What I want is replace the `2` at the 10th line with the `HALLS_REGISTRATION.ID` returned from the outer select, so when I try this approach,

```
SELECT
  HALLS_REGISTRATION.ID,
  (
    CAST(
        (SELECT
           HALLS_REGISTRATION.MONEY_RECEIVED_NUMERIC
         FROM
           HALLS_REGISTRATION
         WHERE
           HALLS_REGISTRATION.ID = ROOT.HALLS_REGISTRATION.ID)
        AS DECIMAL
    )
    +
    (SELECT
       SUM(
           CAST(
               HALLS_REGISTRATION_PAID.PAID_MONEY
               AS DECIMAL
           )
       )
     FROM
       HALLS_REGISTRATION_PAID
     WHERE
       HALLS_REGISTRATION_PAID.REGISTRATION_ID = HALLS_REGISTRATION.ID
    )
  )
FROM HALLS_REGISTRATION AS ROOT;
```

DataGrip treats Root as an unresolved symbol and I get this error on execution

> [42S22][42122] Column "HALLS_REGISTRATION.ID" not found; SQL
>   statement:

I would like the query to be compatible with H2, MySQL or both.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) Also, I think you should decide which of those two RDBMSs you want this to be for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is not about `ROOT`, but the second sub`SELECT`, instead.

```
SELECT
  ROOT.ID,
  (
    CAST(
        (SELECT
           HALLS_REGISTRATION.MONEY_RECEIVED_NUMERIC
         FROM
           HALLS_REGISTRATION
         WHERE
           HALLS_REGISTRATION.ID = ROOT.ID)
        AS DECIMAL
    )
    +
    (SELECT
       SUM(
           CAST(
               PAID_MONEY
               AS DECIMAL
           )
       )
     FROM
       HALLS_REGISTRATION_PAID
     WHERE
       REGISTRATION_ID = ROOT.ID
    )
  )
FROM HALLS_REGISTRATION AS ROOT;
```

I am not certain, that you need all those sub-queries...

Try something like this:

```
SELECT r.id, r.money_received_numeric + SUM(p.paid_money)
FROM halls_registration AS r
LEFT JOIN halls_registration_paid AS p ON r.id = p.registration_id
GROUP BY r.id;
```

Comment: This first one gave the same error but the second one worked like charm and is much more simple, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
SELECT
  HALLS_REGISTRATION.ID,
  (
    CAST(
        (SELECT
           HALLS_REGISTRATION.MONEY_RECEIVED_NUMERIC
         FROM
           HALLS_REGISTRATION, HALLS_REGISTRATION_PAID
         WHERE
           WHERE
       HALLS_REGISTRATION_PAID.REGISTRATION_ID = HALLS_REGISTRATION.ID)
        AS DECIMAL
    )
    +
    (SELECT
       SUM(
           CAST(
               HALLS_REGISTRATION_PAID.PAID_MONEY
               AS DECIMAL
           )
       )
     FROM
       HALLS_REGISTRATION_PAID
     WHERE
       HALLS_REGISTRATION_PAID.REGISTRATION_ID = HALLS_REGISTRATION.ID
    )
  )
FROM HALLS_REGISTRATION;
```

will probably do what you want.

Comment: This actually gave me this error

Scalar subquery contains more than one row; SQL statement:

But thanks for spending time on it!